# Executing a program in the PATH via `System.Diagnostics.Process` in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a program that is in the PATH (and in the command line, I can execute `program-name` and it runs as expected). This is in the *system* PATH environmental variable (so I believe all users should be able to access this program this way).

However, my ASP.NET application is not able to execute this application when I set the filename with just the file name (ie, with `process.StartInfo.FileName = "program-name"`). It says that it's not able to find the file. It works if I use the full path (ie, with `process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:/Program Files/Something/program-name"`).

I tested a Windows Forms application and it doesn't have this problem (that is, either approach works for it). So what is ASP.NET doing differently? Is there any way I can avoid having to specify the full path? I expect the user to have this program in the PATH and would prefer not to make them specify the location (which is also more work).

Comment: As an aside, the PATH seems outdated in ASP.NET when I print it with `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH")`. The printed value has a different path for the binary in question (it was located on a network drive and I figured that might have been the reason for this issue). I don't know why it would be outdated. It persists even after restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programs in the system PATH are indeed found. But the manner of updating the PATH is a little weird. It's insufficient to just restart the IIS server. I had to restart the physical machine to get the new PATH recognized.

The other guy's comment about needing "special permission to invoke a process" doesn't seem correct. Also, ASP.NET certainly seems to be aware of environmental variables by default (I used the system PATH for simplicity, but since you can run an IIS server as specific user, you could probably utilize their environmental variables, as well).

Answer (score 0):

Why would one want to run a process from Asp.net application in first place. Asp.net is server/client technology so running a process would run on Server side  rather than client which itself will have security issues if you're going to host it on IIS server. You will need to give special permission to invoke a process on Server.

Second, Considering the above Asp.net wouldn't be aware about the Server machine's local configuration including the Environment variables unless you ask for it explicitly, Means you can achieve it but by doing so manually from your code. All you need to do is search for the Exe you want to launch in Path variable.

Here's the snippet that will do the needful for you.

```
public static string FindExePath(string exe)
{
    exe = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(exe);
    if (!File.Exists(exe))
    {
        if (Path.GetDirectoryName(exe) == String.Empty)
        {
            foreach (string test in (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH") ?? "").Split(';'))
            {
                string path = test.Trim();
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(path) && File.Exists(path = Path.Combine(path, exe)))
                    return Path.GetFullPath(path);
            }
        }
        throw new FileNotFoundException(new FileNotFoundException().Message, exe);
    }
    return Path.GetFullPath(exe);
}
```

Comment: There's plenty of reasons to run local programs. In my case, I'm running FFmpeg to perform conversion on recorded video that was streamed through this server. Other uses could include running a compiler (as I imagine services like IDEone do) or another type of conversion software (there's a number of file conversion sites and they all do the conversion server side).

Comment: @Mike yes, there's no barring of doing things in programming but there are practices to do things in a proper way. What if Asp.net application launches a process and it doesn't terminates properly or May be the application have launched a number of processes but how will you keep track(monitoring) of all of them?  IMHO, Asp.net application should only serve it's purpose by serving it's client. For server side processing you can go for WCF Services. Always keep your options open for scalability.